# IllegalStateException:Template is in a loading state but lists are added, or vice versa

Tags: android, android-auto

I want to use EventBus to set new state and rerender Android Auto Screen.

```kotlin
package com.capsule

import androidx.car.app.CarContext
import androidx.car.app.Screen
import androidx.car.app.model.*
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode


class CarPlayScreen(carContext: CarContext) : Screen(carContext) {

    private var template: Template
    private var eventBus = EventBus.getDefault()

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    fun onCapsuleStateUpdate(state: CapsuleState) {
        template = GridTemplate.Builder()
            .setTitle("Temperature: ${state.temperature}C")
            .build()
    }


    init {
        eventBus.register(this)

        val row = Row.Builder()
            .setTitle("Wait state update")
            .build()
        val pane = Pane.Builder()
            .addRow(row)
            .build()

        template = PaneTemplate.Builder(pane)
            .setHeaderAction(Action.APP_ICON)
            .build()

        invalidate()
    }

    override fun onGetTemplate(): Template {
        return template
    }

}
```

#### When I run app on emulator I see init template

[image]

#### But after calling `onCapsuleStateUpdate` rerender doesn't work and in console I see:

```
E  Could not dispatch event: class com.capsule.CapsuleState to subscribing class class com.capsule.CarPlayScreen
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Template is in a loading state but lists are added, or vice versa
at androidx.car.app.model.GridTemplate$Builder.build(GridTemplate.java:282)
at com.capsule.CarPlayScreen.onCapsuleStateUpdate(CarPlayScreen.kt:24)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:517)
at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:444)
at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:421)
at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:394)
at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at com.capsule.CapsuleBleManager.followState$lambda$10(CapsuleBleManager.kt:190)
at com.capsule.CapsuleBleManager.$r8$lambda$6x0OdCCBxFndfQ6AFD4N11VDXro(Unknown Source:0)
at com.capsule.CapsuleBleManager$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onDataReceived(Unknown Source:2)
at no.nordicsemi.android.ble.ValueChangedCallback.lambda$notifyValueChanged$0(ValueChangedCallback.java:184)
at no.nordicsemi.android.ble.ValueChangedCallback$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Description of the error

> IllegalStateException – if the template is in a loading state but there are lists added, or vice versa, or if the template does not have either a title or header Action set.

But I can't understand why template is in loading state if it was rendered. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `GridTemplate` is not marked as loading but also has no content to display.

I'm not really sure why you're using a `GridTemplate` if there's no content to display in it, but you can fix this issue by either marking the `GridTemplate` as loading by calling [`setLoading(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/model/GridTemplate.Builder#setLoading(boolean)) on the builder or by calling [`setSingleList(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/model/GridTemplate.Builder#setSingleList(androidx.car.app.model.ItemList))  with an `ItemList`.

Comment: Thank you!
After filling in a content it has worked!